# How to allow user to see sales made in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-community-builder

So I have community builder installed and joomshopping and my client wants to be able to view any sales he has made but he can't have access to the back end of Joomla. Is there any way to allow him to see them without logging into the back end or just giving him access to that one area?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to limit his admin access. see: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=673&t=749774